# Deleting an object doesn't update an association already in memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We are using Rails 3.2.5

Here is the code we are using:

```
class MR < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :codes

  def test
    codes.each { |c| c.delete }
  end

  def asdf
    codes.size
  end
end
```

if I call this:

```
mr = MR.create 
# imagine mr has 5 codes
mr.test
# confirmed that 5 codes have been deleted from database using Sequel Pro
mr.asdf => 5
mr.reload.asdf => 0
```

Do I always have to reload the association when deleting the objects within it? Is there a different method I should use? I thought destroy would do it but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use `#count` instead of `#size`

`#size` caches the value. `#count` runs the query each time.

Comment: I think you should have left it bold :P

Comment: ahaha. It was the `#` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch data directly from database. instead of cache

```
def asdf
  codes(true).size
end
```